# How to set values for react-select with dynamic rendering of select fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I was working on rendering dynamic select fields and trying to set the values for them . Let me explain clearly what i am trying .

At first i have this useState :

```
  const add_actions_options = [
    {value : "val1" , label:VAL1},
    {value : "val2" , label:VAL2 })}
  ]

  const [ actions , setActions ] = useState<any | undefined>([{type : add_actions_options[0].value , label : "" , data : ""} ])
```

Initially 1 select field is rendered , but later i have a button which renders more select fields ( **Max 4 select fields** ) below is the related code for dynamic rendering of Select fields fields:

```
  function addAction(){
    if(actions.length < 4 ){
      setActions([...actions , {type : add_actions_options[0].value , label : "" , data : ""}])
   } else {
    toast('max 4 allowed', { type: "error" })  
    }
  }

  
  const handleTypeChange = (index, value) => {
    const updatedFields = [...actions];
    updatedFields[index].type = value;
    setActions(updatedFields);
  } 

  const handleLabelChange = (index , value) => {
    const updatedFields = [...actions];
    updatedFields[index].label = value;
    setActions(updatedFields);
  } 
  const handleDataChange = (index, value) => {
    const updatedFields = [...actions];
    updatedFields[index].data = value;
    setActions(updatedFields);
  } 


 <button className='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block' onClick={() => addAction()}>{intl.formatMessage({id: 'ADD.ACTION'})}</button>

 <div className='row my-6 '>
                      {actions.map((item , index) => {
                          return(
                            <div key={index} className='row my-6'>
                               <div className='col-4'>
                                 <h4><label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'TEMPLATE.TYPE' })}*</label></h4>
                                 <Select
                                    defaultValue={add_actions_options[0]}
                                    onChange={(value) => handleTypeChange(index, value)}
                                    options={add_actions_options}
                                  />
                               </div>
                               <div className='col-4'>
                                 <h4><label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'TEMPLATE.LABEL' })}*</label></h4>
                                 <input
                                      
                                      className="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                                      name='action.label'
                                      type="text"
                                      maxLength={30}
                                      onChange={(event) => handleLabelChange(index, event.target.value)}
                                      value={actions.label}
                                      required
                                     />
                               </div>
                               <div className='col-4'>
                                 <h4><label className="form-label">{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'TEMPLATE.DATA' })}*</label></h4>
                                 <input
                                      
                                      className="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                                      name='action.data'
                                      type="text"
                                      maxLength={100}
                                      onChange={(event) => handleDataChange(index, event.target.value)}
                                      value={actions.data}
                                      required
                                     />
                               </div>
                              
                            </div>
                          )
                        })}
    </div>
```

Here's what i wanted to achieve  , the data and label values for actions are working as expected , but the value is being set differently when i choose options from select dropdown,

Initially if i do not change any values for select component it is working as expected , the output :

```
0: {type:'val1' , label : 'qwe' , data:'ujm'}
1: {type:'val1' , label : 'ujhn' , data: 'uhn'}
```

Note : In above scenario I am just rendering one more select fields and initially the type is set to add_actions_options[0].value , but if I try to select val2 from the dropdown the output turns to :

```
0: {type: {value: 'val2', label: 'VAL2'} , label : 'qwe' , data:'ujm'}
1: {type:'val1' , label : 'ujhn' , data: 'uhn'}

//DESIRED OUTPUT WHEN I CHOOSE DIFFERENT OPTION IN SELECT TAG
0: {type: 'val2' , label : 'qwe' , data:'ujm'}
1: {type:'val1' , label : 'ujhn' , data: 'uhn'}
```

I just want the val2 to be placed within type , but its placing whole selected option , can anyone help me pass this ? Would be great help for me !

Regards